# CardView contents not respecting match_parent

Tags: android, view, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create something very simple: a `CardView` that stretches to screen height and has a `TextView` inside it which should stretch to the card width. I have made the card fill the screen vertically with `android:height="match_parent"` on the `CardView`. However, now the `CardView` contents, like a simple `TextView` will not stretch across the whole card horizontally when setting `android:height="match_parent"` on the `TextView`. It just looks like `wrap_content` instead.

Note that this `CardView` is being placed inside a `RecyclerView` with a horizontal `LinearLayoutManager`.

Note that setting `android:layout_width="match_parent"` on the card does not actually stretch it out to the screen width when using a horizontal `LinearLayoutManager`, and the opposite is true if using a vertical `LinearLayoutManager`! I think this has something to do with my problem.

Here is the CardView xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="6dp"
card_view:contentPadding="8dp"
card_view:cardElevation="8dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_video_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="2sp"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView_preview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#80000000"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:text="Preview"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView_set"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#80000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:text="Set"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the RecyclerView xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:gravity="center"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_wallpapers" tools:context=".WallpapersActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/cardList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: @Yvette No, not in the scenario I've set out anyway.

Comment: I seem to have solved this by adding android:alignLeft and alignRight of the widest element, to the elements I need to stretch across. But I don't understand why match_parent won't just work.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by placing the `CardView` inside a `RelativeLayout` as the outer-most layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        style="@style/CardLayout">

        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have problem with your `inflater`.
I had similar problem and changed my inflater from:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.services_card_list_item, null);
```

to this:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.services_card_list_item, parent, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working code. please try it.

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FeedListRowHolder> {


    private List<FeedItem> feedItemList;

    private Context mContext;

    public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<FeedItem> feedItemList) {
        this.feedItemList = feedItemList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public FeedListRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row,viewGroup, false);
        FeedListRowHolder mh = new FeedListRowHolder(v);
        return mh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FeedListRowHolder feedListRowHolder, int i) {
//        feedListRowHolder.title.setText("set data");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

**OR**
Replace with your code.

```
LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_listitem, viewGroup, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

This was actually a bug in an early version of the RecylerView library. I forget exactly in which version it was fixed, but I think it was somewhere around support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0 where it was fixed.